# Mark as Answer your answer to your own question after enough votes

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, self-answer

One should be able to mark as answer their own answer to their own question after a certain amount of upvotes.

I think 10 would suffice.

Why the two day wait for a good self-answer!?

Answer (score 3):

"Accept" is mostly superficial - the primary intent is to allow the asker to indicate the answer he found helpful. Since this is pretty valuable information in many cases, it also has the side-effects of pinning the accepted answer to the top of the list.

"Accept" for self-answers is *entirely* superficial. Folks wanted a way to indicate that the solution they eventually implemented was the one they'd written up themselves. Because there's no small amount of bias involved, the pinning behavior doesn't apply. The waiting period ensures that self-answered questions don't become too discouraging to folks who might otherwise post competing answers.

If you get 10 up-votes on an answer you posted to your own question, it should be pretty obvious to any observer that you've produced a good solution. You don't really need to accept it *at all*, but if you do eventually decide that it's the best of the lot you're free to do so.

Comment: If accepting is entirely trivial, then surely a 2 days waiting period is over the top.